# Anr while accessing AssetManager

Tags: android

I get ANR while executing following snippet

```
String[] fontTypeArr = mContext.getAssets().list(path);
```

I'm trying this from background thread, It throws anr in this sometimes

```
main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x755a3000 self=0xb8c5c048
  | sysTid=10050 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f8ebec
  | state=S schedstat=( 1094690359 1522806824 1233 ) utm=84 stm=25 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe0ad000-0xbe0af000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  native: pc 000000000000f9e8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: pc 0000000000013bd7  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex+42)
  native: pc 0000000000013f6d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+310)
  native: pc 000000000000d9bb  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (???)
  native: pc 000000000000ee23  /system/lib/libandroidfw.so (_ZN7android12AssetManager10isUpToDateEv+12)
  native: pc 000000000001b247  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_content_res_AssetManager_isUpToDate__+82)
  at android.content.res.AssetManager.isUpToDate (AssetManager.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfo (ActivityThread.java:1776)
- locked <@addr=0x12cdc260> (a android.app.ResourcesManager)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.getPackageInfoNoCheck (ActivityThread.java:1750)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2595)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700 (ActivityThread.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1394)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5290)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:911)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Getting anr while accessing path lists from AssetManager api. The number of cases are very few though. Not able to find anything around this.

Comment: Post your Source with AssetManager

Comment: String[] fontTypeArr = mContext.getAssets().list(path);                                               I'm trying this from background thread, It throws anr in this sometimes.

Comment: i have try this and no anr. Whats is path

Answer (score 0):

The following principles will help you to prevent unnecessary crashes and ANRs

1. Make sure requested resource available in the appropriate folders(assets/raw).
2. Use application context `mContext.getApplicationContext()` to access resources. Resources are meant to be application level, so context too needs to be same level.
3. Add `try{} catch{}`, wherever iostreams are used. As `AssetManager` depends on the stream. Print the stacktrace in catch block.
4. Make sure your generated APK supports all types of [ABI (Android Binary Interfaces)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)